# Find out my SMTP username & password

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

Am using php mailer for sending e-mail from wamp server. It requests for SMTP username & password. What is it actually ? Am completely new to this environment. Can anyone ans me this please ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you already have an SMTP server ? (it could be your own mailbox from yahoo, google...) if it's ONLY used for test purpose with very few emails)

Comment: I have my own google account. Is that called SMTP server ?

Comment: you should learn how works mail server.  search for SMTP and IMAP you will quickly get it and understand what kind of settings  wamp expects.